# React component's defaultValue does not work

Tags: reactjs, input, components, fetch, default-value

I'm trying to use a fetched value from DB as a default value (shown until the component is clicked) of an input field.

However, using "defaultValue" attribute, the fetched value it is not displayed.

App.tsx file (value is fetched successfully):

```
  const [Income, setIncome] = useState<string>('0');

    useEffect(() => {

    const incomeResp = async () => {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/income')
      .then(
        result => setIncome(result.data && result.data.length > 0 ? result.data[0].income : 0))
    }
    incomeResp();
  }, []);


  return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <IncomeExpensesContainer 
            income={Income}
            setIncome={setIncome} 
            totalExpenses={TotalExpensesAmount} 
            currencySymbol={Currency}
          />
      </div>
```

Component's file:

```
interface Props {
    income: string;
    setIncome: (value: string) => void; 
    totalExpenses: number;
    currencySymbol: string;
}

const IncomeExpensesContainer: React.FC<Props> = ({
        income,
        setIncome, 
        totalExpenses, 
        currencySymbol,
    }: Props) => {


   const [insertedValue, setInsertedValue] = useState<string>(income);

return (
    <Grid container spacing={1} className="income-expenses-container">
        <InputItem 
            onChange={setInsertedValue}
            onBlur={setIncome}
            title="Income" 
            type="number" 
            placeholder="Your income" 
            defaultValue={income}
        />
    </Grid>
);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is ur return statement in App? How do u pass the data to the components file? So many missing informations.

Comment: @Delice I've added return statement of the in App.tsx. What additional information is needed?

Answer (score 1):

***Edited after additional information provied***

Use the passed prop in your component:

```js
const Component = (props) => {
       return (
            <InputItem 
              onChange={setInsertedValue}
              onBlur={setIncome}
              title="Income" 
              type="number" 
              placeholder="Your income" 
              defaultValue={props.income}
        />
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing (I've just updated the code in order to show that)

Comment: I think the problem is that defaultValue is initialized on first render on component. The first time you render the component - your state is probably empty. Can you try render your input component only if your state has value? E.g. `{income && <IncomeExpensesContainer [...] />` and see what happens?

Comment: I've replaced `defaultValue` by  `value` and it didn't help.

Comment: I've also added conditional rendering to this component {<stateThatChanges> && <IncomeExpensesContainer [...] />} and it works as expected - is rendered once the state changes, however, it's initial value = 0, so, the issue is not solved

Comment: I've finally figured out the solution: 1) created const [insertedValue, setInsertedValue] = useState(income); and assigned value={insertedValue} 2) used useEffect(() => { setInsertedValue(income) }, [income]);

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who encounters this problem in the future, the solution that worked for me was to use the in-built type casting methods of javascript when passing number type values.
This for example

```
const Component = (props) => {
       return (
            <InputItem 
              onChange={setInsertedValue}
              onBlur={setIncome}
              title="Income" 
              type="number" 
              placeholder="Your income" 
              defaultValue={props.income}
        />
}
```

when called should receive the defaultValue as

```
<InputItem 
        onChange={setInsertedValue}
        onBlur={setIncome}
        title="Income" 
        type="number" 
        placeholder="Your income" 
        defaultValue={income.toFixed(0)} // toString and toPrecision work as well 
    />
```

I think it is something taking place under the hood of the React Native TextInput component, though I don't have any resource justifying this.

Hope it helps.